# add a numeric value to an element using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

if i have an xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD ID="1">
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD ID="2">
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>31</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

how i could add to each price element the value of 1000, so there is a sum like current value + 1000, using xslt-3?
Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD ID="1001">
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>1010</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD ID="1002">
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>1031</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: The version of XSLT does not really matter, if you want to transform the `PRICE` elements or their contents then write a template matching those elements and compute the new value. I am not sure how your XSLT snippet relates to the desired output.

Comment: an example of your approach please? My snippet was another attempt i have made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write a template for the `PRICE` elements and handle the rest by `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy) you get

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="to-be-added" as="xs:decimal" select="1000"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="PRICE">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select=". + $to-be-added"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2j

Comment: How should i alter the above, in order to add also the 1000 to the CD ID number?

Comment: @binegud, well, follow the same approach and write a template matching `CD/@ID` and then recreate that same attribute with the desired new value using `xsl:attribute`.

Comment: again, i would appreciate a xslfiddle, an image is a thousand words, thank you, or should i post a new question instead?

Comment: You really need to show some effort and try on your own, there is nothing to your question in the comment that can't be solved given the example answer to the original question and the hint to use `xsl:attribute`. I will add the link to the spec section on https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#creating-attributes.

Comment: i have tried, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kw but no result...

Comment: `xsl:copy` is to create a shallow copy of a node, in the case of a match on `CD/@ID` you don't want a copy, you simply want to recreate the attribute and give it a new value, so remove that `xsl:copy` and you should get the result you want. It is however easier to simply use the `select` attribute `<xsl:attribute name="ID" select=". + $to-be-added"/>`.

Comment: thank you very much, this is why i asked, the select is the best approach